# ¿Cómo obtener los índices de sublistas vacías de una lista anidada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo `palabras` la cual es una lista de listas. Lo que quiero hacer es obtener en `Indices` los índices de las sublistas de `palabras` que están vacías, de manera que al imprimir en consola `Indices` su resultado final sea `[1, 2, 4]`

Lo que tengo de código es:

```
palabras = [['carro rojo'],[''],[''],['avión'],['']]

for p in range(len(palabras)):
    Indices = [i for i,x in enumerate(palabras[p]) if x==''] 

print(Indices)
```

Mas sin embargo al imprimir `Indices` el resultado en consola es `[0]`, lo cual no es la salida esperada.
Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta es:

```
palabras = [['carro rojo'],[''],[''],['avión'],['']]
indices = [i for i in range(len(palabras)) if palabras[i] == ['']]
print(indices)
```

La parte

```
i for i in range(len(palabras))
```

tiene a `i` recorriendo desde 0 hasta `len(palabras)`. Por cada valor de `i`, preguntamos si el correspondiente elemento es igual a la lista `['']`. Si se cumple la condición

```
if palabras[i] == ['']
```

entonces agregamos el indice a la lista en creación.

El resultado es:

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

Nota: La sublista `['']` **no** es una lista vacía. Tiene un elemento, que es una cadena de largo cero. La función `len([''])` retorna 1.

Una lista vacía es así: `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, no necesitas usar un bucle for con una comprension de listas. La comprension de listas iterará directamente sobre tu lista.

En segundo lugar, la funcion enumerate te permite obtener el indice, sin necesidad de integrar el indice p a palabras.

y en tercer lugar si es una lista de listas, lo que buscas dentro de tu lista es una lista, por lo que deberias buscar x==[''] en vez de x==''.

```
indices_listas_vacias = [indice for indice, palabra in enumerate(palabras) if palabra==['']]
print(indices_listas_vacias)

>>>[1, 2, 4]
```